# can't start docker-compose services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

when I run this docker compose file I have a strange error. that you can see under the text. I'm new with dock so can anyone help me with this.

The error:

```
ERROR: The compose file './docker-compose.yaml is invalid because:
services.wordpress.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object
```

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
    version: "3.7"
    services:
      db:
        build:  ./db
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib.mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Test123
          MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
          MYSQL_USER: wordpress
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: Test123
        networks:
          website_network:
            aliases:
              - wordpress
      wordpress:
        build:
        container_name: wordpress_new
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        networks:
          website_network:
            aliases:
              - wordpress
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: Test123
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks: 
      website_networks:
        name: website_network
    volumes:
      db_data:
          driver: local
          name: db_data
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please do not provide code, logs, output, error messages... in images: in most cases it is barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, it prevents people trying to help you to copy/paste content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `services.wordpress.build` config option needs a value after it like you did in `services.db.build: ./db`. This value represents where to find your Dockerfile and the context where Docker will try to build your image.

Check [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) on how you can specify the build option.

This is what your file should look like in the wordpress section:

```yaml
  wordpress:
    build: BUILD_PATH_HERE # you need a value here if you're building a new docker image
```

Per the docs, note that if your Dockerfile has an alternate name or you need a special [build context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context), you'll need to specify those values as well as an object. For example:

```yaml
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: ./some/context/path # can be a relative or absolute path
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate-name
```

Alternatively, if you're using a prebuilt image, you can specify:

```yaml
  wordpress:
    image: IMAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the build property value.

```
wordpress:
    build: SOMETHING NEEDS TO BE HERE
    container_name: wordpress_new
```

A path to where the build runs or a more complex object. Probably just the name of the folder where the container sources are.
This is how it can look like: [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWXty.png) if it is an object. And this is how it can look like if it is just a path: [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLuX.png)

More info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build